# LoadRuner CPU is extremely high with TLS enabled

Tags: performance, security, ssl, tls1.2, loadrunner

I have load runner app which is running some flow. Connection to my app is over https. Problem is that CPU is extremely high when TLS is enabled. I tried to configure keep alive setting and increase connection timeout - it didn't help.

Is there any way to disable handshake between load runner and my app, because it is not something I am testing. For example when i use "curl" I could use flag --insecure.  I didn't sound such configuration in load runner.

Comment: Which protocol are you using? Which version of LoadRunner? Which flavor (SA/PC/Controller)?

Comment: protocol - https. version of LR- 12.5.3. tls version TLSv1.2 Flavor - controller.

Comment: Can you try on the latest version? There were many major refactors done in this area over the past 2 years.

Comment: Any other options?

Comment: Unless you get an answer here you will need to go through the official support channels I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Which CPU?

- CPU on Server where TLS handshake is taking place?
- CPU on load generator host, running exclusive of the controller, for a single virtual user and above?
- CPU on combined controller, load generator for all virtual users?

As to disabling?  It is recommended that your load use the same mechanism as users.  If users connect insecurely in production, then by all means use the same HTTP (vs HTTPS) connection leveraged by end users.   Otherwise the use of resources on your server infrastructure will be very different than production.  This will make your test both less predictive and of lower diagnostic value for bottlenecks in resource utilization.